# Why does the text field get filled at the start, but not when I push my button?

Tags: javascript, html, function, numbers, addeventlistener

I am trying to put the result of a simple function into an HTML text field after a button is pressed.

The value is correctly filled in when the app starts, but it doesn't do anything when I click the button.

This is what I have so far...

```js
function machToMph(mach) {
  var mph = mach * 767.269148;
  return mph;
}

// gathering information from HTML elements
function onClickMethod() {
  var mach = document.getElementById("machs").value;

  //I cant exactly figure out what is going wrong here, or if im missing anything
  var mph = machToMph(mach);
  var result = mph;
  document.getElementById("mph").value = result
}

function init() {
  var button1 = document.getElementById("btn");
  button1.addEventListener("click", onClickMethod());
}

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

```html
<input id='machs' type='text' value='10' />
<button id='btn'>Click me</button>
<input id='mph' type='text' />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `onClickMethod()` should be `onClickMethod`. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is incorrect :

```
button1.addEventListener("click", onClickMethod());
```

You're adding the result of the function `onClickMethod` as a listener instead of the function itself.

This is what you actually want :

```
button1.addEventListener("click", onClickMethod);
```

If you also want the value to be pre-filled, add this line as well :

```
onClickMethod();
```

#### Demo

```js
function machToMph(mach) {
  var mph = mach * 767.269148;
  return mph;
}

// gathering information from HTML elements
function onClickMethod() {
  var mach = document.getElementById("machs").value;

  //I cant exactly figure out what is going wrong here, or if im missing anything
  var mph = machToMph(mach);
  var result = mph;
  document.getElementById("mph").value = result
}

function init() {
  var button1 = document.getElementById("btn");
  button1.addEventListener("click", onClickMethod);
  onClickMethod();
}

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

```html
<input id='machs' type='text' value='10' />
<button id='btn'>Click me</button>
<input id='mph' type='text' />
```